# Very stupid question about non-linear equations.. :D

Tags: nonlinear-system

This will get me lots of negatives because I won't be able to explain myself and it is a bit of a personal quandry, but!! :p - 
Why are non-linear system solutions searched for using a linear numerical system? .. 
By linear numerical system I mean that between 0 - 1 and 1 - 2 , 2 - 3 etc, there are the same quantity (same infinity) of numbers.. 
Can you create a numerical system where that quantity differs?
So say an interger only numerical system of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,12,14,16,18,20,25,30,40,50.. as an example of a non continuous one.. (in this case 3*7 = ? (As 21 does not exist.. is not defined))

Comment: The idea has been used for a long time, most strikingly in log and log log graph paper, and slide rules.